# Returning a Component from Angular Pipe

Tags: angular, pipe

I'm working with alot of tables in my latest project. I've developed a Dynamic MatTable Component to simplify my tasks (handling sorting, filtering, searching, paginating and a couple of other jobs) here is an example.

`<app-dynamic-mat-table [Data]='data' [ColumnDef]='ColumnDef' ...>`

here is what my column def object looks like:

```
ColumnDef = [
   {title:'MyColumnTitle',value:(v)=>v.MyProperty,pipes:[new MyPipe()]},
   ...
];
```

Array of pipes are applied one by one to the value of each cell, now I need more than just text formatting and HTML, I need some of my pipes to return an instances of components, is there a way to Instantiate a component in my pipe and return it? so I can continue my tasks with this base code without modify my DynamicMatTable Component? I'll be glad reading your experiences handling similar situations though.

BTW MyPipe is a Standard Angular Pipe.

Comment: I'm not so sure that you can return an _instance_ of a component, however you can certainly generate components dynamically using [`ComponentFactory`](https://angular.io/api/core/ComponentFactory). There is also a [guide](https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader) on how to do this.

Comment: @MichaelDoye - Thanks for the tip, I'll try it. looks like this job is beyond responsibilities of a pipe and I was wrong by expecting this. I'll have to modify my base code a bit.